# Socket.io path on client, how to match it to my node.js server directory tree?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path, socket.io

I'm using socket.io over node.js, with Expressjs.  When I serve up my html page, I have the socket.io.js file link hardcoded in a script tag:
`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

I'm not sure how to match that to my directory tree.  It is as follows:

[image]

It resides buried down in the 'node_modules' folder.

My index.js looks like this:

```
const PORT = 3000;
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
const http = require("http").Server(server);
const path = require("path");
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")));
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/css"));
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/js"));


server.listen(PORT, function() {
      console.log("server listening on port " + PORT);
});

 io.on("connection", function(socket){
      console.log("user connected");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to change `server.listen` to `http.listen` and it will work

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it.